# Firefox 5 rendering is very different from the previous version

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-5

Firefox 5 renders my site very weirdly. I use Blueprint CSS framework. It was ok before Firefox 5.

For example,

[image]

The HTML code for the capture is:

```
<div class="span-24 last">
<table class="stripe">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="span-2">Date</th>
<th class="span-15">Subject</th>
<th class="span-2">Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td>09/28/2009</td>
<td>
<a class="subject" href="/posts/278?locale=en">acts_as_list scope</a>

</td>
<td>
<a title="Edit" class="icon" href="/posts/278/edit?locale=en"><span class="ss_sprite ss_page_white_edit">&nbsp;</span></a>
<a title="Delete" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="icon" href="/posts/278?locale=en"><span class="ss_sprite ss_delete">&nbsp;</span></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td></td>
<td colspan="2">
<p>acts_as_list :scope =&gt; :parent (_id is optional. Use symbol instead of string)</p>
<p>acts_as_list :scope =&gt; 'board_name = \'#{board_name}\''</p>
<p>If scope column is not 'xxx_id', use the form above.</p>
<p>use single quote.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>http://macdiggs.com/2007/08/27/customizing-scope-in-acts_as_list/</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<hr>
</div>
```

Or sometimes, th cells in a tr are wrapped in multiple lines.

[image]

```
Here's related css:
.column, .span-1, .span-2, .span-3, .span-4, .span-5, .span-6, .span-7, .span-8, .span-9, .span-10, .span-11, .span-12, .span-13, .span-14, .span-15, .span-16, .span-17, .span-18, .span-19, .span-20, .span-21, .span-22, .span-23, .span-24 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
* html .column, * html .span-1, * html .span-2, * html .span-3, * html .span-4, * html .span-5, * html .span-6, * html .span-7, * html .span-8, * html .span-9, * html .span-10, * html .span-11, * html .span-12, * html .span-13, * html .span-14, * html .span-15, * html .span-16, * html .span-17, * html .span-18, * html .span-19, * html .span-20, * html .span-21, * html .span-22, * html .span-23, * html .span-24 {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.span-15 {
  width: 590px;
}
```

I created a jsFiddle example at http://jsfiddle.net/cgTaB/

What's going on?

Sam

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case that shows the same problem?

Comment: Could you please provide the CSS you are using for this particular piece of code :)?

Comment: personal preference here: I DESPISE `blueprint.css`.  `screen.css//grid.css` is one of the most disgusting CSS files I've ever seen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the `* html` in any part of the second selector. That makes every one of the parts of that selector extremely inefficient.

Comment: I created a jsFiddle example similar to the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/cgTaB/

Comment: I think that the table cells must be arranged in a grid format no matter what style I impose on them. So this is really weird.

Answer (score 1):

I've been fiddling with your code and I think I found the problem. You are using:

```
display:inline
```

and

```
float:left
```

in your headers. Remove these properties and add a `width` to your `span-2` class.

Let me know if this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're applying a style of `display: inline` to the `th` elements.  Although not explicitly defined as block elements, [th elements are considered block elements](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html) because they can contain block-level elements.

While this may have been just an innocent mistake on the designer's part, I prefer to think that it's because blueprint.css is a poor stylesheet ;)

If you apply `display: table-cell` to your `th` elements **after blueprint.css**, as in [this update to your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgTaB/1/), it should display fine.

Another reason to dump blueprint as fast as you can.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The surprise was that the same code worked fine with Firefox 4. Thanks!